# How to make mp3 playlist with RPi 3

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie, omxplayer

How I can make playlist with omxplayer or omxplayer-wrapper?
What I mean playlist, is something that can play next .mp3/.wav file automatically. You know, something like in mp3 player....

or It would be lovely if you can tell me how to play next file automatically with omxplayer!

I use RPi 3, jessie
python 2.7.9(if I have to use omxplayer-wrapper)

and if you know how to make playlist without using omxplayer, please let me know

I'm really struggling at this, pls help! (

Answer (score 3):

Would a shell script be OK?

```sh
    for song in /path/to/*.mp3
    do
            omxplayer "$song"
    done
```

This will play all MP3 files in a directory. You can replace `/path/to/*.mp3` with a list of individual files if you want to be more specific.

Comment: External scripting is just about the only approach there is for omxplayer playlists. I can't remember where I've stuck the link, but I'm sure I've read comments from the creator/maintainer along the lines of 'it's not supposed to play playlists and I'm not developing the feature'.

Comment: I found the link: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/370#issuecomment-143769260

Comment: thanks, but is there any other way to do this? I can't use mp3's GUI because I'm gonna use mine...

Comment: @SeonghunYang I don't understand what is *mp3's GUI*, but anyway, take a look at [omxplayerGUI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=75602): it should give you an idea on how to design a GUI for the player.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [mkpl](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/mkpl) (make_playlist) command line tools:

```
cd myalbum
mkpl myalbum.m3u
```

or order by name

```
cd myalbum
mkpl -o myalbum.m3u
```

If you have affinity with python code, also with python scripts:

```py
from make_playlist import *

# Prepare playlist list: find multimedia files with name starts between a and f
playlist = make_playlist('/Music/collections',
                         '^[a-f].*',
                         ('mp3', 'mp4', 'aac'),
                         recursive=True,
                         unique=True)

# Write playlist to file
write_playlist('/Music/AtoF.m3u', 'wt', playlist)
```